# vue popup input get focus automatically

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i am using vue 2.x

i have a html looks like(and this html file is included in a jsp file):

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="myDiv">
        <input type="text" v-model="input" @click="showPopup"/>
        <div id="popupDiv" class="modal fade" role="dialog"
         aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <textarea id="textArea" v-model="textarea" ref="popup"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        myVM = new Vue({
            name: 'myVM',
            el: 'myDiv',
            data() {
                return {
                    input: '',
                    textarea: ''
                }
            },
            methods: {
            
                showPopup() {
                
                    jQuery("#popupDiv").modal('show');
                    this.$refs.popup.focus();
                }
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

when user click this `input`, the popup dialog(bootstrap modal) will be shown.

now i want the `textarea` of popup dialog get focus automatically when popup dialog shown, so i tried to use `this.$refs.popup.focus()` in `showPopup()`, but it doesn't works. `autofocus` also doesn't work.

sandbox is https://t7huy.csb.app/

Comment: Add autofocus attribute to the textarea.

Comment: <textarea v-model="textarea" ref="popup" autofocus></textarea>

Comment: If you are triggering the popup by `v-if` or `v-show` on `#popupDiv` - you should wait for the `$nextTick` before trying to focus the textarea - otherwise if it is not yet visible the browser will ignore the request for focusing.

Comment: @shahidiqbal i tried `autofocus` before, it doesn't work too.

Comment: @IVOGELOV it is not triggered by `v-if` or `v-show`, it's a bootstrap modal.

Comment: I assume that Bootstrap provides synchronous function to show the modal - so after calling the function we can be certain that the input is already in the DOM. If so, you can simply call the `focus()` method of the input field after the modal is shown.

Comment: Open the modal inside the showPopup:
$('#popupDiv').modal('show');
this.$refs.popup.focus();

Comment: Remove data-toggle and data-target attributes if you used them.

Comment: showPopup(){
  $('#popupDiv').modal('show');
  this.$refs.popup.focus();
}

Comment: @IVOGELOV i tried `jQuery("#textArea").focus()`, it doesn't work too.

Comment: If you want us to debug the issue - we need a CodeSandbox.

Comment: @IVOGELOV i added the sandbox link at the bottom, plz check, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open bootstrap modal in `showPopup` method`

```
showPopup(){
  $('#popupDiv').modal('show');
  this.$refs.popup.focus();
},
```